# Bootstrap Form Spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Ive been working on this form but I am now having trouble getting things to line up properly. On smaller sizes its not to big an issue, but on large screens the problem is very noticeable.

Two main issues I am finding is that I have some social links that is getting extra spacing from somewhere, though there is no padding or margins between them that I can see. Also the actual form itself is not filling in the whole space. Im not exactly sure how to fix the spacing issues here.

Anyone offer any tips?

Here is a JsFiddle of the code the code saved to SO and Jsfiddle are exact same, though it appears they are giving different results. Not sure why, though clearly I probably messed something up here.

https://jsfiddle.net/Tsukiyono/aq9Laaew/283640/

Here is another link showing things on my gitpages link: 
https://tsukiyonocm.github.io/test/

*edit* A image of the layout I am trying to achieve.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX7jV.jpg

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}


/** Contact
---------------------------------------------------------*/

#contactus {
  color: black;
  max-height: 62.5rem;
  width: auto;
}

.contact-title {
  font-family: futura-pt-condensed, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.contact-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-contact {
  max-height: 15rem;
}

.social {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.custom-social {
  max-height: 15rem;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.social-contact ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-contact ul li {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.btn-sub {
  letter-spacing: 1.5;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  white-space: normal;
}

.btn-form {
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 1.5;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
}

form {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="contactus">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="display-3 contact-title">Contact Us</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="row contact-info d-flex flex-md-row flex-lg-column">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 custom-contact">
            <h3>- Our Office -</h3>
            <address>
                                SOCKEROO Marketing<br>
                                123 Address Rd.<br>
                                Pittsburgh, PA<br>
                                15222<br>
                                <a href="tel:+555-555-5555">TEL - 555.555.5555</a><br>
                                <a href="mailto:sockeroomarketing@gmail.com">Email - sockeroomarketing@gmail.com</a>
                            </address>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 custom-social">
            <p class="social">- Say Hello -</p>
            <div class="social-contact">
              <ul class="">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-inverse fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-inverse fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-inverse fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-inverse fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-sub">Subscribe to Our Newsletter</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 m-0 p-0">
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company or Organization">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us a bit about your project, timeline, and budget"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-form">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what is the issue... You want the social links to be closer together?

Comment: Sorry, still working on my wording of things as I am learning. If you look at this link:
https://tsukiyonocm.github.io/test/
You will see that the "say hello", links and button sit below the bottom of the form. I basically want those to line up with the bottom of the form. So they need to go up or the form needs to spread out down. I just dont know whats causing the spacing on the left side.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see multiple things contributing to that: first is that you have `justify-content: center` on `.custom-social`, since you have `flex-direction: column` it will center the items inthe middle vertically, you could remove that and they will stay at the top of the box, reducing the distance between both boxes on that column

Comment: Another thing is that the size for the columns on the left causes you button to not be able to display its text on a single line, you could fix that by increasing the column size, removing more space vertically

Comment: You say both pieces of code are *exactly* the same?

Comment: except for a few script/links for bootstrap, as far as I can tell they are the same. The actual html for the form was a copy paste job, but it is possible I guess that I didnt get all the scripts added into stackover flow. Jsfiddle I selected the bootstrap startup so I assumed it had it.

Comment: Yeah looking again it does seem it is exactly the same, though if I copy the "working" css and paste it on the other page, it doesn't work as intended

Comment: Being honest I don't know what might be causing this, upvoted question since its an odd behavior and maybe someone will see it that can identify the issue

Comment: I uploaded an image of the layout I am aiming for. Ive been banging my head on this issue for days now and this is even the second time I have tried to recreate it now figuring I am doing something wrong. lol

Comment: Thanks for the help. After stepping away for about 8 hours I came home and was able to narrow things down from the below poster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the inconsistency between JSFiddle and Github pages, I believe the problem lies in the way bootstrap implements their `col-md-6` class. Namely, the **flex-basis property.**

For reference, this is what I see their class to be, based on the element inspector in chrome:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-md-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

(A little context: `flex` is shorthand for defining `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`, in that order. You can find that info in this article on CSS-Tricks: [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-13) and a little more detail on flex basis just above it, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-12)).

As you can see, they're setting `flex basis` to 50%. Once I set both the jsfiddle and gitpages' `flex` property to `flex: 0 0 auto`, the spacing was consistent on both of those pages, leading me to wonder if `flex-basis` is calculating 50% to be one value in the JSFiddle and another value in your Github pages. As for a solution, what you can do is create a custom class, let's say `.cust-col-md-6`, and copy the ruleset defined by bootstrap, but change the flex-basis of the property to `auto`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.cust-col-md-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Then from here you can set that as your class instead of using `.col-md-6`:

```
<div class="col-12 cust-col-md-6 custom-social">
```

Comment: I marked this correct even though it didnt *quite* fix my problem. With the above changes I still was having alignment issues. Though, the Flex was what I needed to change. I did have to create two different custom classes (had the issue on xs and lg)  I had to set the flex to auto and initial respectively and create two media queries for them.